# how to create registration form by passing parameters using post method in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, api, post, parameter-passing

I'm trying to perform a POST request to a Api. The idea is to make a request with parameters:name,email,mobile num, password.
The problem is that those parameters are not recognized by the server.
I do get a "Success" as response.
here is my code

```
-(NSData *)newUser:(NSString *)newUserName andMobNo:(NSString *)mobileNo andEmail:(NSString *)emailId andimei:(NSString *)imei andPassword:(NSString *)pswd andSESSION_ACCESS_KEY:(NSString *)accessKey andPhoto:(NSString *)photo andFbloginId:(NSString *)fbID
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.tugain.com/contest/TugainAPI/setUserDetail"];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NEWSIGNUP,newUserName,mobileNo,emailId,imei,pswd,accessKey,photo,fbID];
    NSData *myJSONData =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myJSONData]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    return returnData;
}
```

Here is my sign up method

```
-(void)signUpAction:(id)sender
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
    NSString *str=@"User";
    [hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(callingMethod:) onTarget:self withObject:str animated:YES];
}

-(void)callingMethod :(NSString *)str
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataLoadMethod:) withObject:str waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)dataLoadMethod :(NSString *)strCon
{
   NSString *photo =@"NO_PIC";
   NSString *fbID =@"0";
   NSString *accessId = @"akjsda9s8dadandlakd9";
   NSString *imei = @"34343434";

  if([strCon isEqualToString:@"User"])
  {
      NSData *returnData;
      if(self.regEmailTxtFld.text.length>0)
      {
            BOOL val=[self validEmail:self.regEmailTxtFld.text];
            if(val)
            {
                returnData =[[WebServices alloc] newUser:regFullNameTxtFld.text andMobNo:regMbleTxtFld.text andEmail:regEmailTxtFld.text andimei:imei andPassword:regPswdTxtFld.text andSESSION_ACCESS_KEY:accessId andPhoto:photo andFbloginId:fbID];
            }
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"Please Provide a Valid Mail-id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                [self performSelector:@selector(dismissView:) withObject:alert afterDelay:2.0];
            }
        }

    if(returnData.length > 0)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"New Customer SignUp resp is %@",res);
    } 
    else //if data is null
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"Error in Response" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissView:) withObject:alert afterDelay:3.0];
    }
}
```

i am passing photo, fbid, accessId, imli also

Comment: your `else //if data is null` is missing `if` condition!!!?

Comment: that is the end of my loop? if data is null it shows alert!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lays in preparing HTTPBody. From my experience, what I always do while creating a `application/json` type request is creating a proper `NSDictionary` first and then serializing it using `NSJSONSerialization` methods.

Using your code it would look something like:

```
-(NSData *)newUser:(NSString *)newUserName andMobNo:(NSString *)mobileNo andEmail:(NSString *)emailId andimei:(NSString *)imei andPassword:(NSString *)pswd andSESSION_ACCESS_KEY:(NSString *)accessKey andPhoto:(NSString *)photo andFbloginId:(NSString *)fbID
{

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.tugain.com/contest/TugainAPI/setUserDetail"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = @{
                                     @"userName-key" : newUserName,
                                     @"mobileNo-key" : mobileNo,
                                     @"emailId-key"  : emailId,
                                     @"imei-key"     : imei,
                                     @"pswd-key"     : pswd,
                                     @"accessKey-key": accessKey,
                                     @"photo-key"    : photo,
                                     @"fbID-key"     : fbID
                                     };
    NSData *httpBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:0 error:nil];
    [request setHTTPBody:httpBody];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    return returnData;
}
```

If this is the solution, remember to change dictionary keys to proper values and check if each of values exists before putting it into the dictionary, because you'll get a crash otherwise.

Comment: @MangiReddy, Ok. Can you tell us what is the server response then? For ex. by logging returningResponse and/or error in `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` method. Because if you get a 'success' response, then maybe there is a server-side problem like bad validation.

Comment: response is "success"